# Can I safely put a PCI-E 6+2 cable into a 12v4 slot on Enermax 1000W PSU?

Tags: power-supply, cable, pci-express

I have an Enermax Revolution87+ 1000W PSU.

It came with a total of 6 PCI-E 6+2 cables. (and some other cables, but that's the one I need information about)

The red 12v4 slot, which appears to be the same as the other two that are plugged in, but they are listed as 12v2 and 12v3, is empty.

Would I be able to effectively use the power supply if I were to buy an additional PCI-E 6+2 cable and plug it into the 12v4 or does the 12v4 imply more than the location of the slot?

I wouldn't want to fry the motherboard by trying to generate too much power to it.

Comment: You don't want to plug PCI-E cables into your motherboard....

Comment: Stop calling every connector or socket a *"slot"*.  If it doesn't look like a slot (e.g. long and narrow), then it should not be called a slot.

Comment: What motherboard do you have that has 3 12v connectors?

Comment: It's for an antminer C1 Liquid cooled, so motherboard isn't even an appropriate term, since apparently we're doing semantics now :P

Comment: The only device I am asking questions about is the PSU, and whether or not the 12v4 slot, it is long and narrow with 12 pinholes, and is where you can plug the 6+2 PCI-E cables in. I have no idea why you're talking about motherboards ramhound lol.  

I've fried a mobo using a pci-e video card before and it was related to noobish improper power supply usage, but the plug was in the video card, not the motherboard, I had no intention of plugging them into a motherboard, but into the PCI-Express cards on the mainboard of the antminer.

Comment: Ah, I see, I must have accidentally clicked the motherboard tag, or it was automatically inserted.  Removing that tag to clear confusion.

Comment: To oversimplify and expand my question:

Can I use a PCI-E cable in the 12v4 slot and run it to a PCI-Express card without worry of damage to the motherboard? The answer that I do not have that makes me want to ask about it is "does 12v2 12v3 and 12v4 mean the same thing, and the number after v mean position, or does it imply voltage or something?"

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to use the 12v4 channel on the PSU to plug into the motherboards 8 pin power connector.

[image]

All the cables are keyed if they are meant to plug in they will fit.  Generally if you put the +2 on the correct side of the 6 pin connector it should work.

You can't overpower the motherboard, it will only draw as much as it needs.

[image: wiring diagram]

**Note:** The green arrows indicating the 12v3 channel.  The different 12V indicators indicate different power channels.  12v1,12v2,12v3, and 12v4 mean the total amount of 12V available is divide in 4 parts.  Each channel has a portion the total amps.  See how each channel/rail has 30A.

Think of this way, you can use a firehose or use 4 regular garden hoses.  The danger of a firehose is if it gets free it will fly around dangerously, and will have enough force to damage people and property.  The 4 garden hoses are much smaller and easier to use.  A 90A short circuit is much harder to deal with than a 30A.

In a 1000w psu this is done to protect the system if you had all the amps on 1 channel any short or power overdraw could melt the wires and damage your system.

Comment: I want to plug it into pci-e cards, but you did answer my question, thanks!  I can indeed utilize that socket or slot or whatever it's called to provide power to the pci-e cards in the antminers if I just buy an additional 6+2 cable.  Thanks for this awesome thorough response!

Comment: but yeah, I wanted to use the pci-e connectors in the pci-e cards.  There's 8 ports in total on the antminer, only 6 plugs on the cables that came with the power supply.  Now I know that the indications are more about load balancing and the 12v4 doesn't imply what I was concerned about.

Comment: If you need an 8 pin connector, indeed you need to get another 6+2 cable for your power supply.